# How do I make smoother rotation for my objects in my game?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am making a game where insects from the top of the screen come down. The object of the game is to kill these insects. I have made a code for these insects on how they move, but what seems to be the problem is that they seem to rotate in a non smooth pattern. They twitch! 
This is the code:

```
 else // Enemy is still alive and moving across the screen
    {
        //rotate the enemy between 10-5 degrees
        tempEnemy.rotation += (Math.round(Math.random()*10-5));
        //Find the rotation and move the x position that direction
        tempEnemy.x -=  (Math.sin((Math.PI/180)*tempEnemy.rotation))*tempEnemy.speed;
        tempEnemy.y +=  (Math.cos((Math.PI/180)*tempEnemy.rotation))*tempEnemy.speed;
        if (tempEnemy.x < 0)
        {
            tempEnemy.x = 0;
        }
        if (tempEnemy.x > stage.stageWidth)
        {
            tempEnemy.x = stage.stageWidth;
        }
        if (tempEnemy.y > stage.stageHeight)
        {
            removeEnemy(i);

            lives--;
            roachLevel.lives_txt.text = String(lives);
        }
    }
}
```

}
Another problem that I am experiencing is that some of the insects are going along the edge of the screen. The user can barely kill them because half of their bodies are on the screen, and the other half are off. Can I make them move a bit away from the edge, like an offset? Thank you!

Comment: Are you doing this on every frame?

Comment: I am doing this on each object in the array. There is no animation, all of it is powered by action script

Comment: Animation can also happen by actionscript, if you change something (x,y,rotation) at every frame. You are mistaken to think animation only happens when using keyframes and such in the timeline. Here's a great book dedicated only to animating things by code in AS3. http://www.amazon.com/Foundation-Actionscript-3-0-Animation-Making/dp/1590597915

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it looks like they are twitching because you're changing the rotation by a large amount right away:

```
tempEnemy.rotation += (Math.round(Math.random()*10-5));
```

Instead you should interpolate/animate to your desired rotation instead of just jumping right to it. There are a few ways to do this, but not sure how your animation is set up.

To keep insects from going right to the screen edges you could put in an offset and limit the x/y positions.

Such as going:

```
var offset:int = 100; // limits the max x to be 100 pixels from the right edge of the stage

if (tempEnemy.x > (stage.stageWidth - offset)){
    tempEnemy.x = stage.stageWidth - offset;
}
```

Comment: The only animation I have is the insect's legs moving. Rotation and movement is powered by actionscript. I don't want a big rotation, just some rotation where the insect can change direction when it's moving downwards. The rotation and movement should all be random as well

Comment: I'll take a guess and assume your above code is being run every frame. Applying a small bit of random rotation directly every frame is going to result in twitchy behaviour just by its nature. You can see this exactly if you plotted out the values of: Math.round(Math.random()*10-5); You'll see a series of random jumps resulting in a jagged line as opposed to the smooth motion you want.

Comment: I'd suggest using a different method to produce smooth random behaviour. A bit more complex, but maybe take a look flocking algorithms (namely the steering/wandering part).

Comment: Is there a way to give each insect a random define pathway? Like one insect will zip from one point, to another point. Then a different insect in the array may go straight down?

Comment: Sure, that can be doable. You could implement this in a variety of ways. One method that comes to mind is just generate some random waypoints for each insect when spawned and have the insect move/steer towards them (part of this can actually be found in a flocking algorithm, which is why I suggested it).